# Sqlite3 (node.js) returns [object Object]

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, object, node-sqlite3

I am trying to use SQLITE3 to store data for my discord bot and here i need to save a number that goes up each time a command is used.
Here is my code: (creating table and setting the value to 0.)

```
  db.run("CREATE TABLE gbanCases ( number INT )")
  db.run("INSERT INTO gbanCases (number) VALUES ($number)", {
    $number : 0
});
```

Trying to see what number returns:

```
        var caseNumber = db.run("SELECT number FROM gbanCases")
        console.log(caseNumber)
```

The thing is that caseNumber returns me "[object Object]" and I want it to return the 0 that was setted up earlier.
Please help me if you can, i'm still very new to this.

Comment: Replace your current log with `console.log({ caseNumber })` and see what you get.

Comment: Here is what i get:
```{caseNumber: Database}
caseNumber:
Database {filename: 'database.sqlite', mode: 65542}
[[Prototype]]:
Object```

Comment: Don't use `db.run()` for a `SELECT` query, use `db.get()` or `db.all()` depending on whether you want 1 row or all rows. They take a callback function that receives the results.

Comment: how can i fix it? sorry if im asking to much, im new

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `db.get()` to get the result of a query, not `db.run()`. The resulting row is passed as an argument to the callback function.

```
db.get("SELECT number FROM gbanCases", function(err, row) {
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }
    console.log(row.number);
})
```

Comment: console.log(row.number);

returns : "{}1"

Comment: I suspect `{}` is coming from something else, not this. `row.number` shouldn't contain that.

Comment: How can I fix it? I'm supposed to get 0.

Comment: I can't think of any reason why it doesn't work. The `{}` is not coming from my code, it must be coming from something else you're doing.

Comment: Maybe i didn't do this correctly : `  db.run("CREATE TABLE gbanCases ( number INT )")
  db.run("INSERT INTO gbanCases (number) VALUES ($number)", {
    $number : 0
});`

Comment: That part looks fine to me. Can you view the contents of the table from a regular sqlite query tool?

Comment: What do you see if you do `console.log(row)`?

Comment: `console.log(row)` returns `{number: '{}1'}`

Comment: That's really weird. I don't know why an `INT` column would have a string like that in the value.

Comment: In the same database file (not same table) I got string columns, i'm going to create a file for this table

Comment: is this code alright ? : `db2.run("UPDATE gbanCases SET number = ?", row.number + 1)`

Comment: I think `row.number + 1` should be in an array. `[row.number + 1]`

Comment: I managed to fix it,  0 is now returned, thank's so much for all your help!

Comment: Is it possible to use row.number everywhere in my file? If yes, how so?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call